# SQL Server : how to select the closest ID of the record closest alphabetically

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table (sample data below) with IDs and company names.

Users can input a search for a company. If that company does not exist, my stored procedure needs to return the ID of the company that would be the next in order alphabetically.

So, using the data below (which is the result of

```
SELECT Id, CompanyName 
FROM COMPANY 
ORDER BY CompanyName
```

If my user searches for **A C M Mechanical Services Inc**, it does not exist in the data, and the ID returned by the stored procedure should be 15410 (A D M Marine) because alphabetically, A C M Mechanical Services Inc would fall in between record ID 16616 (A C I Controls) and 15410 (A D M Marine).

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
ID      CompanyName
------------------------
12295   A 1 Vending
16638   A B C RENT ALL
 8288   A Best Inc
16616   A C I Controls
15410   A D M Marine
12326   A Granchelli, Developer
 8687   A Greener Solution
13895   A H S Systems, Inc.
10914   A L Design Inc
16943   A L J Electrical Constr Co.
 1099   A Lunt Design Inc.
15623   A M Carpet Service
16618   A M Miller and Associates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause that checks for the name to be equal to or greater than the name sought `ORDER BY` the name an limit the result to the top one record using `TOP`.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE companyname >= 'A C M Mechanical Services Inc'
       ORDER BY companyname;
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple and that I was overthinking it!